# How can I find plural form for the nouns which are present in the google unigrams?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

I downloaded the unigrams and how can I find plural forms for the all the nouns present in unigrams?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern)?

Pluralization, in particlar: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#pluralization